# Sending to printer whats shown in screen of a C console program

Tags: c, printing, console

I'm learning C, and i've created a schedule that organices days of work for diferent workers.
The manager needs that schedule to be printed in paper just like its shown on the screen.
How can i do that?

[output of the console that needs to be printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9W7i.png)

Comment: That's a platform-specific thing. What platform are you running on?

Comment: Why is not an option to write it to a text file with `myprogram > mytextfile`?

Comment: How do you print it to the console? Depending on operating system it could be easy to adjust it to write to a printer device instead.